# Linear Algebra - Inverse Matrices - Finding inverse of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, inverse-function

I am trying to solve the following problem but unable to come up with a solution.

**Question**: Find $A^{-1}$ given that $(B^{-1} A)^{-1} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 3 & 5 \\
    3 & -2 & 2 \\
    2 & -4 & -7 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ and $B^{-1}=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$.

I will appreciate some help/lead on this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hint:$$(B^{-1}A)^{-1}=A^{-1}B$$

Comment: Thanks Peter! Got it know. :)

Comment: After editing, the question no longer makes sense.

Comment: Jakob by reverting my edit you make your question useless for the next ones because the problem makes no sense as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(B^{-1}A)^{-1}=A^{-1}B$, you can just multiply the two matrices.  That is, $A^{-1}=(B^{-1}A)^{-1}B^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Helped a lot. :)